# Refresh a div using javascript in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have the following file named navbar.php. and I wanted it to be refreshed with a time delay so I used the js function bellow and it works fine. problem is when page refreshed it doesnt go to the actual path, instead it adds the name of the controller and function to the source path and return 404 , help pls.

```
<div class="group" id="mydiv">
<!--some content -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("application/views/templates/navbar.php", function (result) {
            $('#mydiv').html(result);
        });
    }, 15000);
});
```

Chrome console log says : GET http://localhost/HDMSV2/dashbord/Dashbord_Controller/application/views/templetes/navbar.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Use a path relative to the domain, starting with a `/`.

Comment: You can't call view directly (probably you can, but is **really bad** idea). You have to call your controller and load navbar view from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try domain relative path to php file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("/application/views/templates/navbar.php", function (result) {
        $('#mydiv').html(result);
    });
}, 15000);
});
```

But I think you need to go to some controller and create function there that will return you proper values, because it won't make too much sense accessing view file if it isn't populated with data from controller as that is how MVC pattern should work

So in your controller `RefreshController` create function `refresh_navbar()`

```
public function refreshNavbar() {
    $this->load->view('navbar');
}
```

And then your script would go something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("/refresh/refresh-navbar", function (result) {
        $('#mydiv').html(result);
    });
}, 15000);
```

Comment: It found the file but start returning internal server error.http://localhost/HDMSV2/application/views/templates/navbar.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Sure, because you can't access view directly. Instead create function `refreshNavbar()` that will load view `navbar.php` and pass it proper data to render correctly, and then you can fetch that html via ajax